# Hybris Commerce & Hybris DataHub integration

Tags: mysql, hybris-data-hub

I will install DataHub for the first time. I am trying to integrate Hybris Commerce 6.5 and Hybris Datahub. I established hybris commerce 6.5 and mysql 5.7.17. 
I initialized the hybris commerce. Eveything is ok.

How can I integrate DataHub into it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several steps to do this but in a nutshell you will need to do the following. These steps can be referenced on the Hybris Wiki or Hybris Help website for more details.

1) You need to enable the Data Hub extension in Hybris in the localextensions.xml file.

```
 <!--  Data Hub extensions -->
 <extension name='datahubadapter'/>
 <extension name='datahubbackoffice'/>
```

After running a build and starting Hybris this will expose a Hybris adapter API endpoint for Data Hub. For example: http://locahost:9001/datahubadapter

2) You then need to go to Hybris HMC and create a service user that Data Hub can use to authenticate with Hybris. In my case I created a user called datahub-user within the admingroup. There may be a more proper group to put it in.

3) Then you will need to setup Data Hub with Tomcat. This can be found on the Hybris Wiki or Hybris Help website. Within the Data Hub local.properties file you will need to add the following properties to connect to Hybris.

```
targetsystem.hybriscore.url=http://YOUR_HYBRIS_HOSTNAME_OR_IP:9001/datahubadapter
targetsystem.hybriscore.username=datahub-user
targetsystem.hybriscore.password=YourSetPassword
```

4) After starting Hybris and Data Hub you will need to initiate the connection to Data Hub from Hybris. This can be done from the Hybris HMC. On the left menu of the HMC expand "SAP Integration" and then click "SAP Administration". You will see a button labeled "Start Upload". This will initiate the connection of Hybris and Data Hub.

Depending on your business needs there are other steps to consider such as setting up the Mapping Sales Areas to Catalogs in the SAP global configuration area in the HMC and setting up the inbound directory paths if you storing products in SAP Material Master.

Further Reading On Data Hub Setup:
https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8ba79fcc86691014a83e8530484d3892.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Step 1 :
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/14/hybris-sap-integrations-part-1/

Step 2 : 
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/20/hybris-sap-integrations-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use recipe installer.

Go to platform directory and run below command

1. `. ./setantenv.sh` (For Mac)
   `setantenv.bat` (For Windows)
2. Goto Hybris installer directory and run below command
   Note: You will find installer directory inside hybris directory
   `./install.sh -r sap_som_b2b` (for Mac)
   `install.bat -r sap_som_b2b` (for Windows)

Copied from:
https://www.queshub.com/how-to-install-sap-hybris-using-recipe-installer-